# Rufus Scheduler :first_in option unknown with cron

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler, dashing

I am trying to use the Rufus Scheduler (within Dashing) to schedule a cron job, but also have it run once upon the server spinning up. I am following the readme [here](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) where it is saying to do the following:

```
scheduler.cron '00 14 * * *', :first_in => '3d' do
  # ... every day at 14h00, but start after 3 * 24 hours
end
```

When I try to do this, I get the following error in my job:

```
`cron': unknown option: :first_in (ArgumentError)
```

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashing is using rufus-scheduler 2.0.24 ( https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/55f90939eae4d6eb64822fd3590f694418396510/dashing.gemspec#L24 ) which doesn't support the first_in feature for cron.

First_in was introduced for cron in rufus-scheduler 3.0.

It seems you're reading the rufus-scheduler 3.x documentation instead of the 2.x one.

The documentation for rufus-scheduler is at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rufus-scheduler , on top of it, there is the link to the 2.x documentation ( https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/two/README.rdoc ). You'll have better luck there.

A 2.x alternative would be:

```
scheduler.in '3d' do
  scheduler.cron '00 14 * * *' do
    # ... every day at 1400
  end
end
```

Comment: I have roughly the same issue - but I want to run the cron on start-up. Is there a similar solution? Running `SCHEDULER.in '0'` would probably only send the command when the first time begins so not sure this would work in this circumstance.

Comment: Confusing... Open a new question with a clear context, not a "roughly the same" context. Remember, other people cannot read your mind.

Comment: No problem - outlined here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302466/running-a-cron-on-start-up-using-rufus-scheduler-2-x - Thanks